# Small doubt about Dirichlet's problem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of dirichlet s problem:

$\Delta u(r,\phi)=0, r<1, u(1,\phi)=f(\phi)$

Where $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ and

$f(\phi)=\cos^2(\phi)$

I starting by doing following:

Enter the polar coordinates $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$. Deriving:

$u_r=u_x\cos\phi+u_y\sin\phi$.    (1)

$u_\phi=-ru_x\sin\phi+ru_y\cos\phi$. (2)

$u_{rr}=u_{xx}\cos^2(\phi)+2u_{xy}\cos\phi \sin\phi+u_{yy}\sin^2\phi$ (3)

$u_{\phi\phi}=r^2u_{xx}\sin^2\phi-ru_{x}\cos\phi$ (4)

$-2r^2u_{xy}\sin\phi \cos\phi+r^2u_{yy}\cos^2\phi-ru_y\sin\phi$ (5)

Adding equal (3) and equal (5) divided by $r^2$, we obtain

$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\phi\phi}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}-\frac{1}{r}u_x\cos\phi-\frac{1}{r}u_y\sin\phi$

Using (1), we obtain

$\Delta u=\frac{1}{r} (ru_r)_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\phi\phi}$

Therefore in polar coordinates, the problem takes the form:

$\frac{1}{r}(ru_r(r,\phi))_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\phi\phi}(r,\phi)=0$ with $u(a,\phi)=f(\phi)$

my biggest problem is to reach the conclusion that the solution is

$(1+r^2cos(2\phi))$ this is the soluction on the book, but for me the soluction is $\frac{1+r^2cos(2\phi)}{2}$

Thanks for all and any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the facts that

$$u(1,\phi)=f(\phi)=\cos^2(\phi)=\frac{1+\cos(2\phi)}{2}$$

and

$$u(r,\phi)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n(a_n\cos(n\phi)+b_n\sin(n\phi)).$$

For a derivation of the latter formula, see [here](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math336s212/notes/bonclarke/%20PDE%20Notes%20ch%2019.pdf).

Comment: How can I get rid of $a_0$?

Comment: @OlindaFernandes You set $r=1$ and identify the coefficients. For example, the obtained equation $\frac{1}{2}a_0=\frac{1}{2}$ determines the value of $a_0$. Your solution is correct, by the way.